# UIPopOverPresentationViewController from a Container ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I would like to present a PopOverPresentationVC from a ContainerVC (loaded from Storyboard). My code below : -

```
@IBAction func showPopOverVC(view: UIView){
  let embeddedVC: EmbeddedVC = instantantiateVC() // my personal helper method
  embeddedVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
  embeddeVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
  present(embeddedVC, animated: true)
}
```

I keep on getting this error `UIPopoverPresentationController should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.` , though I am setting the sourceView correctly. Any suggestions is much appreciated.

Funnily enough if I remove the line : -

```
embeddeVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
```

The modal presentation works fine.

Comment: What is `view`, are you sure it is not `nil`?

Comment: since its not an optional it cannot be nil.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is you need to set tht popover presentation properties in this order, if you reverse, the app would crash, crazy I say :)

```
embeddeVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
embeddedVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
```